# Unix sort - character comparison algorithm

Tags: python, sorting, unix

I need to have a file sorted with consistent way as Python would do so.

I have some file sorted using Unix `sort` program. After sorting this file, I wrote Python script for checking if that was sorted correctly:

```
with open('my_file_location') as f:
    last_l = next(f)
    for l in f:
        if last_l > l:
            print(last_l, l)
            break
        last_l = l
```

Script failed giving the following entry:

```
('250,8\n', '25,1\n')
```

I experimented a bit with sort tool, to check if the output is actually repeatable and inconsistent with Python comparison algorithm. Finally, I found two interesting cases:

```
 $ echo -e "250,1\n25,8" | sort
250,1
25,8
 $ echo -e "250,\n25," | sort
25,
250,
```

Why these two calls give me two different orders? I consider it a bit weird, because the beginning characters remains the same and only ending changes.

My file is pretty huge and it would be the best for me to stay by my current sorted file. How can I apply the same string comparison in Python?

If it is impossible to implement this comparison quickly, or there might hapen some other issue, how can I sort my file using `sort` again but this time with Pythonly correct comparison algorithm?

**UPDATE**

Example of Python output below (inconsistent with output of Unix `sort` tool):

```
>>> '250,1' > '25,8'
True
>>> '250,' > '25,'
True
```

Contrary to Unix `sort` tool, in Python both comparisons give the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Comment: your current locale affects the order produced by `sort` - `LC_ALL=C echo -e "250,1\n25,8" | sort` should be "consistent" with your example...

Comment: @Chris_Rands Why those two outputs of `echo | sort` calls give me two differ orders and why it does not happen in Python. The question has been updated with the example.

Comment: @ewcz I am afraid that setting `LC_ALL=C` changes nothing

Comment: @ChristianKönig I tried solution with `natsort` package from the question you linked (solution answer) and it didn't work in my case (failed on another entry). I don't think it covers my issue.

Comment: @pt12lol sorry, it should be `echo -e "250,1\n25,8" | LC_ALL=C sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can confirm that the locale is the culprit with:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
L = ['250,1', '25,8']
print(sorted(L, cmp=locale.strcoll))
#['250,1', '25,8']

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C')
print(sorted(L, cmp=locale.strcoll))
#['25,8', '250,1']
```

Comment: `locale.setlocale` and then calling `locale.strcoll` function seems to be solution for my problem.